# Product Image upload issue: File size should be more than 0 bytes

Tags: magento-1.8, image, upload

While using Firefox, when I try to upload an image through the product image uploader I am getting an error saying `"File size should be more than 0 bytes"`. this error doesn't occur in Chrome.

this is what it looks like:
[image]

anyone got an idea what could cause this behavior?

I know this uploader is flash based so I tried already to disable/enable/reinstall my Firefox flash plugin but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you try a different browser?

Comment: As I said it works fine in Chrome but I want it to work in Firefox as it's the main browser I am using.

Comment: Do you browse with https?

Answer (score 0):

Marius debugged this by this method in 1.6 version.

edit

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml

and add this line

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype1.6.js</script></action>
```

Below:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
```

Reference taken from this [LINK](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2011/09/upload-issue-for-magento-1600.html)

I guess this can be helpfull

Comment: I just tried this but it didn't work for me. :(

I even tried to completely replace prototype with the 1.6 version mentioned in your link.

Comment: It may be an issue related to mozilla you need flash for this, check for other broswers, try clearing browser cache

Comment: Were you able to recreate this issue on your machine? I have the latest Firefox and flash versions running on windows 7 and I cleared my cache multiple times.